# Changing PHP variable as compared to Local Time

Tags: php, mysql

I Want to change the contect of $time variable.
as the local time changes
Like If

```
The localtime is Between 9-10am then $time="10:00 - 10:59"
The localtime is Between 10am-11am then $time="11:00 - 10:59"
The localtime is Between 11am-12pm then $time="12:00 - 12:59"
The localtime is Between 12pm-1pm then $time="13:00 - 13:59"
```

& Soo On.!!

For this i Can created a Mysql table name as Time & Have added the value.
& fetching the value in variable $time.

Now Have 24 Hours Cron Jobs & a 24 PHP script to change the value of That sql.
& add the cron  of 24 files on different time to change the value.
But its Too Big Task.

Any One Knows Any Short & Cute Method to apply the different vales in the variabe Only Using PHP.
:)
Thankx In advance..

Comment: Have a look on http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: But i need 1Hour + to the local time & in format "xx.00 - xx:59"

Comment: Well as Tomasz showed in his answer, you can get the hour with the format option H (for all options see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), the only difference with datetime instead of using date is, that you can easily set the preferred time zone for the current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$hour = (1 + date("H")) % 24;
$two_digits = sprintf("%02d", $hour);
$time = "{$two_digits}:00 - {$two_digits}:59";
```